# Find Distinct Best Matches in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I dont know if the title is the best, but its what I got.

What I am looking for is to find the best matches (based on minimum distance) for all values in the first column WITHOUT having duplicate matches in the second column.  For instance, given the following dataframe:

```
first   second  distance
test    test    0
test    testy   1
foo     boo     1
foo     foop    1
bar     boo     2
test    boo     4
test    foop    4
foo     test    4
bar     test    4
bar     foop    4
foo     testy   5
bar     testy   5
```

I want to find the best matches for the three unique values in the first column, but they cannot be the same as anyone else.

In this case, 
test matches with test best; foo matches with boo best; 
bar matches with boo best, however that is used, as is its next best match of test.  So bar must match with foop.

```
test:test
foo:boo
bar:foop
```

I originally tried to do a pandas iteration, but deleting future rows while iterating does not work, it will repeat rows that should have been deleted.

matchedForms is the dict I want at the end, the df is already sorted by distance.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    matchedForms[row['first']] = row['second']
    df = df[df['first'] != row['first']]
    df = df[df['second'] != row['second']]
    if len(df) == 0:
        break
```

It does not have to be a pandas implementation either.

Comment: Have a look at the [hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), implemented in scipy as [linear sum assignment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)

Comment: Yeah looks exactly like what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to warped pointing me in the right direction, here is the solution.

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
first = ['test', 'foo', 'bar']
second = ['test', 'testy', 'foop', 'boo']

arr = [[0,1,4,4],
[4,5,1,1],
[4,5,2,4]]

row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(arr)
assignments = list(zip(row_ind, col_ind))

matchedForms = {}
for one, two in assignments:
    matchedForms[first[one]] = second[two]

print(matchedForms)

{'test': 'test', 'foo': 'boo', 'bar': 'foop'}
```